# How to get a one-to-many result when the MySQL query is based on a second relationship in the related table?

Tags: mysql

I'm a real noob to MySQL and I'm not even certain that the question was worded correctly.

The database has two tables, Products and Feedback. The fields in the Products table are sku and variations. There can be multiple variations for a single sku. The fields in the Feedback table are variation, title, text. There is a one-to-many relationship between Products.variations and Feedback.variations.

The goal is a query that returns the title and text of all Feedback for all of the variations of a single product.

My code doesn't work. In the example below, I want all Feedback when sku='proda'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Products.variations, Products.sku, Feedback.variations, Feedback.title, Feedback.text
WHERE Products.sku='proda'
inner join Products.sku ON Products.variations = Feedback.variations
```

This the error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... near 'WHERE Products.sku='proda'
>   inner joi' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

The literal after an `INNER JOIN` statement should be a table name, not a column name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Products.variations, Products.sku, Feedback.variations, Feedback.title, Feedback.text
FROM Feedback
INNER JOIN Products
ON Products.variations = Feedback.variations
WHERE Products.sku = 'proda'
```

`WHERE` statements go after joins. The `SELECT` also needs a `FROM`.